# Изменение даты и времени при изменении в google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Код который нашел в интернете:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var row = range.getRow(); // Адрес строки активной ячейки
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var name = sheet.getName();
    if (name == "Лист1" && col == 8){ // Если изменения на листе "Лист1" и в колонке H
      if (sheet.getRange(row , 10).getValues()==''){ //Если дата в колонке 10 не заполнена
        sheet.getRange(row, 10).setValues([[new Date()]]); //Заполняем текущую дату
      }
  }
};
```

Как в гугл таблицах при изменении колонки H обновлять дату и время в колонке J, а при удалении данных из H удалять их из J?

Comment: Подскажите скрипт. Например: в гугл таблице на листе делаем ячейку, в которой должно появляться время изменения определенной области из этого листа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  let column = e.range.getColumn();
  let value = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 8).getValue();
  let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd.mm.yyyy H:mm:ss");

  if (column == 8 && value != "") {
    sheet.getRange(row, 10).setValue(date);
  }
  if (column == 8 && value == "") {
    sheet.getRange(row, 10).clearContent();
  }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но есть нюанс - это свойство применяется ко всем страницам в таблице. Можно ли как-то поменять что-бы как в предыдущим варианте применять к определенным листам (пример:  if (name == "Лист1" && col == 8)). Попробовал аналогично сделать у меня не получилось. В скриптах я не силен.

Comment: Разобрался, нужно было внести еще переменную "name", а потом прописывать значения и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше получать лист так:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Название листа")
```